# Proof for the general equation for family of lines passing through the intersection of two lines(Simplified).

Tags: geometry

In the previous post [Proof for the equation of a line passing through the intersection of two lines(family of lines).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2243155/proof-for-the-equation-of-a-line-passing-through-the-intersection-of-two-linesf) I have looked at derivation which seems to be oversimplified so I am still confused.

> Let $C(x_0,y_0)$ be the common point $L_1 \cap L_2$. Thus
>
> $$\begin{cases}a_1x_0 + b_1y_0+ c_1 =0\\a_2x_0 + b_2y_0+ c_2 =0\end{cases}$$
>
> By difference with the initial equations, we obtain the new **equivalent** equations:
>
> $$\tag{1}\begin{cases}a_1(x-x_0) + b_1(y-y_0)=0 \ \ (L_1)\\a_2(x-x_0) + b_2 (y-y_0)=0  \ \ (L_2)\end{cases} \ \ \implies \ \underbrace{(a_1+Ka_2)(x-x_0) + (b_1+Kb_2)(y-y_0)=0}_{\text{line} (L_1+KL_2)}$$

**From equation 1 why do we add a constant $K$ to line $L_2$ and what is its significance?**

Comment: Wouldn't this question best be asked in a comment to [the answer that describes $K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2243505/409)? Alerting the answerer that the response is unclear will allow the answerer to improve that response.

Comment: @Blue It would be a better idea but SE has limit for users to comment(minimum 50 reputations ) and I am short of it.

Comment: I added a comment to that answer to direct the answerer here.

Comment: We were supposed to prove that any lines passing through the intersection of the two lines has an equation of the form $L_1 + KL_2 = 0.$ (Which is not strictly true; what is true is that every such line _except_ $L_2$ has such an equation.) At some time during the proof we were going to have to refer to that equation; how can you prove something that you never even mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe explaining it with vectors will be  clearer.

(see figure below)

A line $L_{P_0,N}$ can be defined by a point $P_0=(x_0,y_0)$ and a normal (= orthogonal) vector $\overrightarrow{N}=(a,b)$ in the following way :

$$M=(x,y) \in L_{P_0,N} \ \ \iff \ \ \overrightarrow{P_0M}=\binom{x-x_0}{y-y_0} \perp \overrightarrow{N}=\binom{a}{b} \ \ \iff \ \ $$

$$(x-x_0)u+(y-y_0)v=0.$$

Thus if you have two straight lines passing through the same $(x_0,y_0)$ with resp. normal vector  $\binom{a_1}{b_1}$ and $\binom{a_2}{b_2}$, taking now the normal vector $\binom{a_1}{b_1}+K \binom{a_2}{b_2}=\binom{a_1+Ka_2}{b_1+Kb_2}$ you will easily be convinced that you get in this way all possible normal vectors, thus all the  pencil of lines passing through $P_0$, *with the exception of the 2nd line itself.*

This is exactly what means the implication I had given, and that you have reproduced above ; indded, it can be written in the following way:

$$\binom{a_1}{b_1} \perp \binom{x-x_0}{y-y_0} \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \binom{a_2}{b_2} \perp \binom{x-x_0}{y-y_0} \implies $$

$$\left(\binom{a_1}{b_1}+K\binom{a_2}{b_2}\right) \perp \binom{x-x_0}{y-y_0} $$

[image]

Comment: How do you come with the formulae $\binom{a_1}{b_1} + K\binom{a_2}{b_2}  = \binom{a_1 + Ka_2}{b_1 + Kb_2}$,I don't know much about vectors but I assume that  $\binom{a}{b}$ is the slope of the orthogonal line.

Comment: First sentence : it is a classical linear combination of vectors. Second sentence : $\binom{a}{b}$ is a vector, not a slope. The slope of the corresponding line (with equation $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)=c \iff y=(-b/a)x+...$) is $-b/a$.

Comment: Can you show $\binom{a_1}{b_1}+K \binom{a_2}{b_2}=\binom{a_1+Ka_2}{b_1+Kb_2}$ in the form of slope of the orthogonal lines?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is a good explanation, and this seems to work for all families.
Let us assume that
$a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$ and
$a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$
which intersect at (x1,y1).
the family is $a_1x+b_1y+c_1 + k(a_2x+b_2y+c_2) = 0$
let ax+by+c=0 pass through (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)

We know $a_1x+b_1y+c_1 + k(a_2x+b_2y+c_2) = 0$ would surely pass through (x1,y1) as the equations in it become 0 when we input (x1,y1).
We can manipulate k such that a1x+b1y+c1 + k(a2x+b2y+c2) = 0 passes through (x2,y2)
Here k can simply be $k=\frac{- a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}$
Now we know $a_1x+b_1y+c_1 + k(a_2x+b_2y+c_2) = 0$ can pass through both (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)
so it is coincident on ax+by+c=0 and so it is basically the same line.

Comment: This site uses MathJax. You can find lots of information about it [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/39599).